# Why doesnt talk utility proceed further? it just displays "Checking for invitation on Caller's machine."

Tags: 14.04

I tried to converse with a friend using talk(talk utility in ubuntu). 
The command I executed was "talk user_name@IP"
The terminal gets divided in 2 parts and it displays "Checking for invitation on Caller's machine."
Also where can I get a step by step info with screenshots(if possible) regarding the usage of talk utility. I read the man page but that didn't help much.